# Remove featured post image inside single post page

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

How can I remove blog post feature image inside the blog single post page from the top, in the "Intution" Wordpress theme ?

Comment: can you paste your code here ?

Comment: i don't know in which file i can update the file to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `element-blog.php` file you'll find the code you want to remove, from the line `24` to the line `29`.

```
elseif(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
<div class="post-image">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(esc_attr__('Go to %s', 'cpotheme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('800'); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

It tests if there any image to show and, if it the case, displays it. Be sure to not remove the line with the `endif` which is right after!

edit: Removing this piece of code will remove the featured image everywhere. If you only want to hide it on the "single post" pages, you can just change the test in the condition. From:

```
elseif(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
```

change to:

```
elseif(has_post_thumbnail() && !is_single()): ?>
```

in the line `24`. This new condition tests whether we are on a single post page or not: if it is the case we don't display anything, otherwise we display the featured image.

Comment: I just installed the theme and remove the lines I quoted above (plus the `<?php` at the beginning of the line `30`) and it works. What did you do to check?

Comment: this is not the appropriate way bro. acc. to this way the blog post also not shown into all post page

Comment: Okay, I thought that it was what you wanted to do. In your case, just change the condition (I just edited my answer).

Comment: yes i was implement it own.. btw thanx for ur help jeremy..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

**element-blog.php**

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('800'); ?>  //line 27
```

which you can remove.

Comment: i am newbie in wordpress. what do u mean by 800 pass in the_post_thumbnail perameter.?